# udev rules issue - Installing STMicroelectronics STlink Tools on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, arm, embedded, udev

I'm trying to get up and running with an STM32F722 Nucelo-144 (with "embedded ST-LINK/V2-1 debugger"). I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

I want to use [STlink](https://github.com/stlink-org/stlink) to flash the device. I've managed to install from source but I am getting stuck at setting udev rules. I've run the following commands, as per instructions:

```
$ sudo cp -a config/udev/rules.d/* /etc/udev/rules.d/
$ sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
$ sudo udevadm trigger
```

I believe this is supposed to create files under /dev/ for stlink devices but nothing going by that name is in /dev/. Also, my board doesn't show up when running "lsusb".

Needless to say, when I run "stutil" it doesn't register my board:

```
usb.c: Couldn't find any ST-Link devices
```

I should also add that I've tried installing with the package manager and again it doesn't register the board:

```
usb.c: Couldn't find any ST-Link/V2 devices
```

To be honest I'm also a little confused as to how to define which generation of debugger to use. For some reason the package manager version seems to default to ST-Link/V2. (my device is V2-1)

Comment: Most likley the udev rules that you are copying need to be changed.  Can you provide 'config/udev/rules.d/*' contents (or look youself).  The matching of the nodes emitted by the kernel (udev) might have changed or udev userspace did.  Typcially, the rule just gives permissions for user space to access the device either by changing the file mode and/or assigning it to some group.  If the debugger doesn't have permission to access the device, it will say something as per above.   `lsusb` will tell you if the kernel has recognized the device; then it is most likely permission.

Comment: @artless_noise Here are the udev rules: [link](https://github.com/stlink-org/stlink/tree/develop/config/udev/rules.d). I'm not sure what I should be looking for in there sorry. If it helps there should be a group called "stlink" for which my user should be a member but this hasn't been setup.

Comment: If the device doesn't show up in lsusb, then there's no point in looking into udev rules. Something is broken in your setup, maybe physically. Read the getting started guide, check your cables, jumpers etc. With a Nucleo-64 (STM32F411) connected, I see this in the output of `lsusb`: "Bus 002 Device 017: ID 0483:374b STMicroelectronics ST-LINK/V2.1".
If you happen to be running Ubuntu on a virtual machine, you have to configure the VM to pass through physical USB devices to the guest.

Comment: @Tarmo, thank you. Literally was just a sketchy USB cable - feel like such a numpty now. - in my defence the board was powered at least. Thanks!

Comment: Great!. I have occasionally been bitten by USB charger cables from cheap devices which only have the 2 power wires in them :)